# PropertyChangeSupport in SWT. How to listen for notifications e.g. in a Table?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javabeans, jface

Using `Jfaces` components I want to know how to detect if the UI control has been changed by the user.
I have seen that there is the interface [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html#PropertyChangeSupport%28java.lang.Object%29) where you can register a [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) but I can not figure out how to use these in an SWT application.
For example I have the following class for my data model.

```
class Person{  
   String firstName;  
   String lastName;  
   String address;  
   //etc  

}
```

This represents essentially a row in an SWT `Table` (the `LabelProvider` will make a row object to be `Person`).
I assume that the class person should have a `PropertyChangeSupport` member variable for the changes, but I can not figure out who registers for notifications?
The `ViewPart`? The `LabelProvider`? Something else?
Any help clearing this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vogella has two very good tutorials on this topic.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) explains how to set up your data structure and include the `PropertyChangeSupport` (however, it is not used in this turorial). An easy method to update your viewer is `viewer.refresh()`. This would have to be called manually.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) tutorial shows how to use DataBinding
(and finally use the `PropertyChangeSupport`) which will notify the listener when change occur.

Comment: I have read this tutorial.Actually the class `Person` **is** from this tutorial.After reading this I have no idea how to use the `PropertyChangeSupport`.Also note that in the tutorial the listener is the `Person` class.Not sure why

Comment: @Cratylus Yes, that's the case for the first tutorial. As mentioned, the `PropertyChangeSupport` is not used in this one. In the second tutorial, it finally is put to use.

Comment: So you are saying I should read the second tutorial to clear this up?